# Firebase_core depends on firebase_core_web and firebase_core_web requires flutter_web_plugins Error when trying to get dependencies of the project

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

So I wanted to continue working on a project I started around 5 months ago. When I left it (the last time a worked on it was like 2 months ago) I was able to run it both in my Android Emulator and in my Chrome browser.

To quickly explain the app, it was a simple login with Google that allowed the user to saw some images once he logged in. I used the following dependencies to achieve this:

- firebase_auth: ^3.1.1
- firebase_core: ^1.3.0

Keep in mind that those versions were the latest (stable) when I was developing this.
I tried upgrading them to the latest version but I also did not work...

When I installed the project on a new computer I got, I was obviously asked to get the dependencies. However, to my surprise, I got the following error:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in project...                           
Because firebase_core >=1.10.0 depends on firebase_core_web ^1.2.0 and firebase_core >=1.2.0 <1.10.0 depends on firebase_core_web ^1.1.0, firebase_core >=1.2.0 requires firebase_core_web ^1.1.0.
And because every version of firebase_core_web depends on flutter_web_plugins any from sdk, firebase_core >=1.2.0 requires flutter_web_plugins any from sdk.
So, because flutter_web_plugins from sdk doesn't exist (could not find package flutter_web_plugins in the Flutter SDK) and project depends on firebase_core ^1.3.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...
```

I also ran Flutter doctor to see if anything was not properly set up, but I got the following output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.258], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.62.1)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

I would really like to continue working on this project, but I am not able to get the dependencies because of the error shown above.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

In pubspec.yaml add `firebase_core:any`. Delete pubspec.lock. run flutter pub get. Then flutter run should work good.

Comment: I'm unfortunately not able to run Flutter run since I don't have the dependencies. I tried adding `firebase_core: any` and removing the pubspec.lock but I got the same error.

Comment: You don't need both firebasecore and firebase core web. Use either one please.

Comment: I'm only using `firebase_core` at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by downgrading Flutter to a previous version.

It seems that the issue was associated with the dependencies I mentioned above not being supported by the version I had. (I downgraded to Flutter 2.2.3 and I was able to run the app like before).

Thanks for the help!